# Is this a known VC14 bug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

The code below gives me a compilation error.

> $ cl.exe VC14-bug.cpp
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x64
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> VC14-bug.cpp
>
> VC14-bug.cpp(41): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'void fails(T1,Poly> *)'
>
> VC14-bug.cpp(41): note: With the following template arguments:
>
> VC14-bug.cpp(41): note: 'T1=int'
>
> VC14-bug.cpp(41): note: 'T2=Kernel'

It is the function f() which poses a problem.  Can anybody reproduce it?

```
template <typename T>
struct Container
{};


struct Kernel {
typedef int Nested;
};


template <class K,
          class C = Container<typename K::Nested*> >
struct Poly
{};


// if f() gets commented it compiles
template<class T>
Poly<T>* 
f()
{ 
    return 0;
}


//template<class T2, class T1> // this compiles
template<class T1, class T2>
void
fails(T1, 
      Poly<T2> *)
{}


// if f() is moved here it also compiles

int main()
{  
    Poly<Kernel> * poly = 0;

    fails(0, poly);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong place for VC bug reports, honestly.

Comment: are you sure it is a bug not just a missing feature from microsoft c++11 compatibility? Have you tried specifying the types in fails explicitly and see if it works?

Comment: If nobody can reproduce it, it might still be buggy code.  I also posted it here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89ecd4d6-e0cf-4ac2-aee0-ca5b484e74bb/compilation-error-with-vc2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: No I have compiled your code on the mac with g++

Comment: But from the issues with had in my work projects I can tell the microsoft is not good with implementing new features and I am not sure whether they have done the template parameters deduction properly yet...

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with the code, and it compiles on Clang and GCC, so I think it's a bug in MSVC. Report it on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: Compiles with MSVC2012, weird.

Comment: A workaround is to add the template parameter T3 to fails and to write Poly<T2,T3>.

Comment: Done https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1750871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is certainly a bug in the template parameters deduction code of VC14.

One possible workaround is to allow all types of containers for `Poly`, in `fails`:

```
template<class T1, class T2, class Cont>
void
fails(T1, 
      Poly<T2, Cont> *)
{}
```

I have verified using [online Visual C++ compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). Unfortunately, one cannot link to test cases [like what we would do on Ideone.com (click to see the compilation with g++-5.1)](https://ideone.com/KiMm0P).